# Are there any prominent modern philosophers with a background in neuroscience?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, neurophilosophy

A lot of timeless questions in philosophy of mind seem relatively answerable by modern advancements in neuroscience and brain science. I was wondering if there are any well-known philosophers to date who have successfully merged their work with a formal background in neuroscience. Steven Pinker comes readily to mind, though I am wondering if there are others.

Comment: Sam Harris.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Harris

Comment: Also, Joshua Greene. He's a good start if you want to read what neuroscience says about ethics, especially ethical dilemmas like the Trolley thought experiment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At least the following researchers have a solid background in both philosophy and neuroscience:

- Patricia Churchland
- Paul Churchland
- Gerhard Roth

Besides their personal homepage I recommend the book

*Susan Blackmore: Conversations on Consciousness (2005).*

It collects conversations with one of the above and some others researchers from either neuroscience or philosophy of mind.

**Added**: Update of the list.

Comment: I don't think e.g. Thomas Metzinger has a *formal* background in neuroscience (see [CV](http://www.philosophie.uni-mainz.de/metzinger/cv.html)).

Comment: Metzinger himself considers his research interest 80% philosophy of mind and 20% neuroscience (personal communication). Due to your comment I made an update of my list :-)

Comment: Thx for the update :)

Comment: I purchased Blackmore's book a couple of months ago, but I am yet to pick it up.  You've inspired me.

Comment: David Chalmers comes to mind, though I think he's more in the cognitive science camp. I think I read somewhere that he worked with Doug Hofstadter for a while. Regardless, he knows his brain sciences.

Answer (score 2):

[Catherine Malabou](http://www.egs.edu/faculty/catherine-malabou/biography/) writes extensively on the intersection of neuroscience and philosophy, most notably in [*The New Wounded: From Neurosis to Brain Damage*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0823239683) and [*What Should We Do With Our Brain?*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082322953X). Her work on plasticity is derived from both Hegel and neuroscience.

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as cognitive science is neuroscience:

**[Daniel Dennett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Dennett)**

Daniel Clement Dennett III (born March 28, 1942) is an American philosopher, writer, and cognitive scientist whose research centers on the philosophy of mind, philosophy of science, and philosophy of biology, particularly as those fields related to evolutionary biology and cognitive science.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I doubt that Daniel Dennett has a *formal* background in neuroscience either (see OP's precise question).